# I am writing lyx layout for workbook with various question types but I am getting error in the layout, which seem to come from the preamble as follow:

Tags: pdftex, errors, lyx, lyx-layouts

Preamble

```
\RequirePackage{fancybox,xcolor,tcolorbox,enumitem,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools,mathrsfs,graphicx,tikz,pgfplots,multicol,tabularx,longtable,array,multirow,hhline,colortbl,booktabs,caption,subcaption,wrapfig,float,framed,mdframed,environ,etoolbox,ifthen,calc,marvosym,pifont,wasysym,fontawesome,hyperref}
```

## Define the colors for the boxes

```
\definecolor{deepgreen}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\definecolor{deeporange}{RGB}{255,140,0}
```

## Define the common options for the boxes

```
\tcbset{
  boxstyle/.style={
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=#1,
    coltitle=white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={
      boxrule=0pt,
      frame hidden,
      size=small,
      rounded corners
    },
    boxrule=1pt,
    arc=5mm,
    breakable,
    pad at break*=2mm
  }
}

# Define the environments for the boxes
\newtcbenvironment{intro}{title}{%
  boxstyle=deepgreen,
  colframe=deepgreen,
  title=#1
}{}

\newtcbenvironment{test}{title}{%
  boxstyle=deeporange,
  colframe=deeporange,
  title=#1
}{}

# Define the commands for the questions and tests
\newcommand{\fillin}[2]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{%
    \underline{\hspace{#1}}%
  }{%
    \underline{\makebox[#1][c]{#2}}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\mcq}[5]{%
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*.]
    \item #1
    \item #2
    \item #3
    \item #4
  \end{enumerate}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{%
    \textbf{Answer:} #5
  }%
}

\newcommand{\msq}[5]{%
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item #1
    \item #2
    \item #3
    \item #4
  \end{enumerate}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{%
    \textbf{Answer:} #5
  }%
}

\newcommand{\match}[3]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XX@{}}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
      #1
    \end{enumerate} &
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
      #2
    \end{enumerate} \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{%
    \textbf{Answer:} #3
  }%
}

\newcommand{\wordcloud}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{%
    \textbf{Answer:} #2
  }%
}

\newcommand{\puzzle}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{%
    \textbf{Answer:} #2
  }%
}

\newcommand{\shortanswer}[2]{%
  \textbf{Question:} #1

  \textbf{Answer:} #2
}

\newcommand{\longanswer}[2]{%
  \textbf{Question:} #1

  \textbf{Answer:}

  \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=deeporange!10,colframe=deeporange]
    #2
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand{\wordproblem}[2]{%
  \textbf{Problem:} #1

  \textbf{Solution:}

  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=deepgreen!10,colframe=deepgreen,sharp corners]
    #2
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
```

EndPreamble

Comment: Welcome. // I wonder who can copy and reproduce what you presented, even with Lyx ... / The better option might be to 1) open the .lyx file of your document with an ASCII editor (it's just plain ASCII), 2) select everything and copy, 3) EDIT your question and paste said content, tagged as code. Thank you // And if you're perfect, you a) reduce your file until it still contains your error, b) add a relevant screenshot about your layout issue.

Comment: Maybe reading “[LyX user questions on TeX stackexchange](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/lyx-user-questions-on-tex-stackexchange)” would be a good idea.

Comment: Just a guess: Could it be, that you've used `#` as a comment character in your preamble code instead of `%`?

Comment: In addition to what others have said, please use a reasonable title, and put your question in the body, not in the title.  And copy the error and paste it here.

Comment: Check what you have really in the preamble  in the Code Preview Pane. Your custom preamble must be only a complement to use some package or custom macro in ERT boxes not already used by  Lyx.  The best that you can do is start with a empty document, add  standard contents: text, figures, tables,... whatever except the Evil Red Text (ERT) boxes with LaTeX code, and only then add a macro o package in the preamble and test it the contents in a ERT box, one by one, to know yourself what are you doing.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I am new here and I guess I lack the experience in posting questions (this in fact is my first question here). I am going to work around what you  have mentioned. The truth is that I am new in using lyx and its layout but I thought I could speed up my writing by creating a layout template for my workbook so I tried learning some few stuffs about lyx layout and got help from AI to write the above code.